# How do I align content at the bottom of a flex container w/o absolute?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I basically have 2 containers which are the same width, but can have varying "heights" depending on their content. I wanted both to also have the same height regardless, adopting the height of whichever was tallest, so I used a flexbox which worked perfectly.

Now the thing is I'm wondering if it's possible to align content at the bottom of both of them.

I essentially have:

```
<div class="flex-box">
    <div class="row event">MetTalks...</div>
    <div class="row shop">Digital Shop...</div>
</div>

.flex-box {
    display: flex;
    width: 66%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 30px;
}

.row {
    flex: 1;
}
```

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLSty.png), they equally take up the row (I only wanted them to span the first 2/3) like I wanted to, and their heights are the same. But I want to be able to align the buttons at the bottom.

I've tried a bunch of things that aren't working, such as making a table div inside, but I can't get the height to stretch to 100% of the row divs

I also can't use position:absolute for the buttons because then they overlap the text as they're taken out of the height calculations.

I even tried making a vertically aligned flex container inside each one, but that also doesn't stretch to 100% height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with absolute positioning, without overlapping the text. You can set a fixed height to the buttons, let's say 50px. Then, you have to apply padding-bottom to the box equal to button's height, + top & bottom margin. So, if you want the button positioned 20px from bottom of the box, you can add a 90px (50 + 20 + 20) padding-bottom to the box. If you can submit the code to jsfiddle, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: So this works really well at keeping the button at the bottom without overlapping the text, but because of the absolute positioning the button's width extends past the the parent (row) containers padding limits when it's shrunk enough

Comment: Actually, setting the width to a percentage seemed to work for some reason. I thought absolute positioning would break that, but apparently it doesn't!